# Retain page final state after back button has been clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser, back-button

I am using asp mvc and have created a page which displays a grid, in which the user is able to update rows. Once complete they click next - to go to the next page. If they click the back button the grid page shows the values that were originally loaded, I need it to show the final values.

**the problem**

- grid page loads
- user edits grid page
- user clicks next button (gets taken to next page)
- user clicks the browsers back button
- grid page loads original values

I have completed some searches but I must be asking the wrong question, I have only found something that uses webforms viewstate. So What do I need to search for to resolve this issue? any guidance would be appriciated.

Comment: Some simple alert on leaving the page reminding the user that they have made unsaved changes would suffice

Comment: You need to identify first that user is navigating by back button. If you were able to do so then you need to use same model state as it was in next page and bind same. Session can be useful. First you need to check whether you really need this behavior as per user experience?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to persist the state of the grid somehow. This can be accomplished one of two ways:

1. Doing a post with the relevant state data when the user clicks next, setting that state in the session, and finally reading the state from the session when rendering the grid.
2. Using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in JavaScript. Basically, you set the state in localStorage each time the user changes the grid, and on page load, you then attempt to load the grid state from localStorage.

The first approach is more universally supported (mostly because all the work is server-side), but requires adding additional logic to your actions and views around this. The second approach is more pluggable: you can just drop in a script that persists/loads the state and nothing else needs to change. However, localStorage is part of HTML5, so it's only available in modern browsers, which basically means IE8+ or any other web browser. That's actually really good, support-wise, but if you need to support IE7, it's not a viable option.